# Threading and synchronization issues

Tags: java, multithreading

### In some cases the following program actually stops (because of Thread 2), when it shouldn't. Why is that happening?

Thread 1: Basically locks `global` and does a while loop.
Thread 2: Attempts to get a lock on `global` and it it succeeds, proceeds to stop the program.

**BUT~** Thread 1 is started first, so technically Thread 2 should never get called and hence the program should never quit.

```
static Integer global = 30;

public static synchronized void setVar(int x, String from)
{
    System.out.println(global + " " + x + " - " + from);
    global = x;
}
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Thread thr1 = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            synchronized(global)
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    setVar((int) (Math.random() * 30), "Thread 1");
                }
            }
        }

    });

    Thread thr2 = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {   
            synchronized(global)
            {
                setVar((int) (Math.random() * 30), "Thread 2");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

    });

    thr1.start();
    thr2.start();
}
```

### Output (That I get once in a while)

> 30 19 - Thread 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is perfectly possible for `thr1` to start and be parked before it hits `synchronized` - then `thr2` gets the lock and exits.

My only concern is how `(int) (Math.random() * 30)` can evaluate to `19`. Now that **is** weird.

Comment: Its casted to an int `0 < x < 29`

Comment: @mk1 - You're American aren't you ... you can always recognise an American ... no sense of irony. :)

Comment: Can you expand on the concept of parked? I am finding that to be confusing in this context.

Comment: The JVM can decide to halt any thread at any time to allow another thread some processor time. This is most common when running a multi-threaded algorithm on a single-core cpu - the JVM will schedule each thread some activity time before parking it and allowing another some time.

Answer (score 1):

The number 1 quote for 90% of all thread-related issues: the order of execution with threads is undefined.

In your example:

```
Thread 1: created, put on hold for whatever reason
Thread 2: created, runs to synchronized and gets lock.
Thread 1: resumed, runs to synchronized, has to wait.
```

So if you write threaded code that uses such synchronized models, you need to be prepared for *all* cases, because which one actually happens, no one can say.

Furthermore on your "should never get called". Yes it is unlikely, but even if the chance is at let's say 1%, that still means within 100 runs it will happen statistically at least once.